# Lua How to create custom function that can be used on variables?

Tags: function, variables, lua

With methods like io.close(), you can use it like this:

```
file:close()
```

Is there a way to create a custom function that works like that, where you can call it on a variable?

For me I am trying to use it to separate arguments from a text file by using string.find to find spaces

So in the text file it looks like

```
this is some input
```

And the readArgs() function should return the entire line in a table with args[1] = "So", args[2] = "in", args[3] = "the" etc. after being called on the line

```
function readFile(file)
    local lines = {}
    assert(io.open(file), "Invalid or missing file")
    local f = io.open(file)
    for line in f:lines() do
        lines[#lines+1] = line
    end
    return lines
end

function readArgs(line) -- This is the function. Preferably call it on the string line
    --Some code here
end
```

Comment: So, to clarify, what you want to do is be able to call `someStringVariable:readArgs()`?

Comment: Yes. Maybe call it on something like string:readArgs() and then have it return a table of arguments or something

Comment: Terminology: functions have values as paramters; not variables. The LHS of `:` is an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description it sounds like you're after something similar to this syntax:

```
local lines = readFile(file)
lines:readArgs(1) -- parse first line {"this", "is", "some", "input"}
```

Metatables can help with this:

```
local mt = { __index = {} }
function mt.__index.readArgs(self, linenum)
  if not self[linenum] then return nil end

  local args = {}
  for each in self[linenum]:gmatch "[^ ]+" do
    table.insert(args, each)
  end
  return args
end
```

You'll have to do a slight change in your `readFile` and attach that metatable to the `lines` you're returning:

```
function readFile(file)
  -- ...
  return setmetatable(lines, mt)
end
```

**Edit**: To answer the OP's comment, a call like this:

```
lines:readArgs(1)
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
lines.readArgs(lines, 1)
```

When the lua VM executes the above line the following happens:

- Does the table `lines` have a `readArgs` key?
- If yes then use its corresponding value as usual for the remaining part of the statement.
- If no, does `lines` have a metatable.__index? In this case it does, so the function assigned to `__index.readArgs` is used.
- `readArgs` is now called with the parameters above: `self` = lines, `linenum` = 1

There is nothing special about `self` here, it's just a regular parameter; you can name it anything you want really.

Comment: What does the self parameter used here represent? The table being called?

I tested the code you provided with the my syntax, and it works just fine, but I would like to be able to better understand this block of code

Comment: I've added some explanation. See if that helps.

Comment: So just to clarify, because Lua couldn't find lines["readArgs"], it looked for __index["readArgs"] inside the metatable?

Comment: Correct, if you query for a key in a table that doesn't exist, lua will consult the metatable as a fallback. If there's no metatable associated with that table then you just get `nil` as usual.