# Lua How to create custom function that can be used on variables follow up

Tags: function, lua

Following up with my previous question (link here: [Lua How to create custom function that can be used on variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340727/lua-how-to-create-custom-function-that-can-be-used-on-variables)), is there a way to create the same kind of function that works for other things other than tables? For example,

```
str = "stuff"
letter = str:foo() --Maybe have the foo function extract the first letter?
```

Is there a way to create a function that works in the same way that

```
lowerCasestr = str:lower()
```

works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All strings share the same metatable, add your custom function to its `__index` table:

```
function first_letter(str)
  return str:sub(1, 1)
end

local mt = getmetatable("")
mt.__index["first_letter"] = first_letter

local str = "stuff"
print(str:first_letter())
```

Comment: What about objects like files? Do they have separate metatables as well? For the matter, do all types of objects in Lua have metatables?